# What are the cases in which Isomap fails to do a good job?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

As above, what is a possible scenario/ dataset/ case in which Isomap fails to do a decent dimensionality reduction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the visualization of [COIL-20 data set](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/software/softlib/coil-20.php) in [t-SNE paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/v9/vandermaaten08a.html):

[image: t-SNE vs isomap on COIL-20 data set]

The data-set consists of images of 20 objects (clusters). In all cases provided in the paper and some cases I found on the Internet ([6000 MNIST data set](https://www.slideshare.net/xuyangela/nonlinear-dimension-reduction), [slide no. 31](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/nonlineardimensionreduction-170226173814/95/nonlinear-dimension-reduction-31-638.jpg?cb=1488130729)), the quality of IsoMap (2001) is not comparable to t-SNE (2008).